# read wsdl file in browser

Tags: xml, apache, wsdl

When i try to open WSDL file in browser (http://localhost/something/file.wsdl), 
i am offered to download that file.
But i want instead of downloading to be able view as XML(string) in browser?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This might happen if your server is not sending the correct content type for the WSDL file.

There should be a HTTP header on the response when requesting the WSDL, something like this:

```
Content-type: text/xml
```

If you see a download popup then maybe this is set to something else, or it is missing altogether.

If you are also using Tomcat with Apache, you could set something like this in the web.xml file:

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>wsdl</extension>
  <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

For Apache, have a look at the [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

It all depend on what browser your using. Try different than your main browser. When you open it in `Internet Explorer 8` you should have XML view.

Comment: Welcome. Please Always mark satisfied answers, it help other users.