# How to open a wsdl file in the browser

Tags: web-services

When I double click on the wsdl file it shows a download window to download that wsdl file, I want to open that file in the browser (I select Internet Explorer to open this kind of file and after that this problem starts),
Can I do something so that when I double click on the wsdl it opens in the browser?

Comment: Then the IE handels wsdls as download. I think you can change it somewher ein the settings. But it's nevertheless an XMLfile which you can open in every editor and normaly in every browser

Comment: if i open in the notepad then how can i get the wsdl url?

Comment: You asked how you can open a WSDL file. To open a WSDL file in Browser you also need the file or the URL to it.

Comment: i have wsdl file but on double click it is not opening in the browser

Answer (score 2):

Browser is not the right tool for this. Open the file with Notepad++ or VS Code or simlar. To change file associations in windows, open the file by right clicking and using openwith.

Answer (score 0):

> i have wsdl file but on double click it is not opening in the browser

Okay here we go:

The problem is, when you open it in **Internet Explorer** (IE) the IE reads the header of the file which would be something like `Content-type: file` because windows handles it as file instead of `Content-type: text/xml`. If it would come from a (proper installed) webservice (even if it's localhost) you would get the right Content-type and it would open in browser as XML. Have a look at this [SQ question (How to open wsdl in browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398167/read-wsdl-file-in-browser). That's a "problem" of the IE.

So I think you can't open it in IE on the way you want to easily. You can try to change your security settings (**Tools -> Internet options -> Security**) and disable "Downloading" - maybe then it will be opened in IE directly. Can't test that on my PC due restrictions but I'm not even sure this will work. And even if yes you'll block all other downloads too!

Alternatives to have a look at your WSDL:

- Open the file with an texteditor, like notepad
- Open the file with another browser, at least Firefox and Chrome show it as XML (didn't try any other browsers)